# Symfony2 use Doctrine in ExceptionController

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Hi I'm trying to use Doctrine inside the default ExeptionController but I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::getDoctrine()

when I try to call:

```
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

What I'm trying to do is to have a custom 404 page where I can present some items from the database.

Could you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: You can use this method becouse ExceptionController dont extend Controller class, You have to extend this class and inject Doctrine to it.

Comment: Thanks, I have extended the Controller class, now the error is: Fatal error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object in (....)/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php on line 198
503 Service Unavailable

Comment: But did you inject Doctrine repository to it ?, past your controller to post and we will look at it

Comment: No, I didn't. The Controller is the default Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController, nothing different inside yet, only that I need to grab something from the database fo show it on 404error.twig.html

Comment: look at this link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

Answer (score 0):

You may also inject the Doctrine service as a dependency in your Controller (in that case you don't need to entend class Controller)

Comment: Could you please give me an example how to inject the Doctrine service as a dependency in the default ExeptionController? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create your own ExceptionController extending the default one. You'll have to declare it as described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#custom-exception-controller. Your custom controller must have a constructor with at least an argument of type Registry (Doctrine). You have to declare that controller as a service in your service.yml (or xml depending on your config) Have a look at the symfony doc for further explanation on how to do that. For the moment I can't help you much more as I'm outside with my Android and it's rather difficult to make long answers

Comment: I'm back home and typing on a real computer. You'll find the docs abouts the service container here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html
It's rather simple and you'll often use these concepts if you work with SF2